# compile and use a realtime kernel on CentOS 7

Tags: centos, kernel, real-time

I would like to compile and use a realtime kernel on CentOS 7. I found a guide on the web:
http://jensd.be/589/linux/complile-and-use-a-realtime-kernel-on-centos-7-or-rhel-7

When I try to use it I can see the new kernel is created, but I get an error on boot:

```
failed to mount /sysroot
```

Comment: What kernel, which patch, and which .config?

Comment: sorry - kernel 3.10.0-514.el7.x86_64 , patch is patch-3.10.105-rt120. .config is according to the one that came with my kernel

Answer (score 0):

I gave up on trying to compile the patched kernel myself and followed this steps in installing a pre-compiled one (versions are configurable):

1. Set up a new repository file called CentOS_rt.repo in /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-rt.repo:

   ```
   # CentOS-rt.repo

   [rt]
   name=CentOS-7 - rt
   baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/\$releasever/rt/\$basearch/
   gpgcheck=1
   gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7
   ```
2. Install the wanted version. For example for kernel 3.10.0-514 and patch number 56:

```
sudo yum install kernel-rt-3.10.0-514.6.1.rt56.429.el7.x86_64
```

3. Reboot and load the patched kernel.

I leave this question open as my solution is not for the original question and if someone has an answer please load it.

Comment: After doing the above, can we change a config in kernel, I mean: where are is the source code ?